# Unique constraint violated - shouldn't be possible, but still... why?

Tags: java, sql, oracle, unique-constraint

I do have a model class:

```
public class LimitsModel {
    private Long id;
    private Long userId;
    private Long channel;
}
```

I also have a unique constraint on my entity set on fields `userId` and `channel`. Throughtout the application, there's no chance those could duplicate.

The limits were added mid development, so we already had users and channels and had to create `limits` entity for every existing user. So we're creating them during some operation and there's no other place they're created. Here's how we create them:

```java
   List<LimitsModel> limits = userDAO.getUserLimits(userId, channel);

   if(isNull(limits) || limits.isEmpty()){
        List<limitsModel> limitsToSave = this.prepareLimits();
            limits = userDAO.createOrUpdateLimits(limitsToSave);
   }
   .
   .
   .
   other operations
```

What I'm getting is

```java
Caused by: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: ORA-00001: unique constraint (USER_LIMITS_UNIQUE) violated
```

Any clues what could be the case? I'm simply drawing the limits from the database, checking if they exist and if not creating them. Where's the place for unique constraint violation?

### EDIT

---

`createOrUpdateLimits` just calls this method:

```
public void createOrUpdateAll(final Collection<?> objects) {
    getHibernateTemplate().executeWithNativeSession(session -> {
        Iterator<?> iterator = objects.iterator();

        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            session.saveOrUpdate(iterator.next());
        }
        return null;
    });
}
```

`prepareLimits` nothing complicated, a simple builder:

```
private List<LimitsModel> prepareLimits() {
    List<LimitsModel> limitsToSave = LimitsModel.CHANNELS.stream()
                    .map(channel -> LimitsModel.builder()
                           .userId(UserUtils.getId())
                           .channel(channel)
                           .build())
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());

    return scaLimitsToSave;
}
```

`getUserLimits`:

```
public List<LimitsModel> getUserLimits(Long userId, Long channel) {
    return getHibernateTemplate().execute(session -> {
        final Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(LimitsModel.class)
               .add(Restrictions.eq(LimitsModel.PROPERTY_USER_ID, userId));

        if (nonNull(channel)){
            criteria.add(Restrictions.eq(LimitsModel.PROPERTY_CHANNEL, channel));
        }

        return criteria.list();
    });
}
```

The constraint is on `userId, channel`. There is a possibility that the block that gets the limits and then creates them is called twice. Shouldn't the new limits be already in the database when it's called the second time? Isn't the transaction commited already?

Comment: Maybe it is already in db.

Comment: code of `createOrUpdateLimits` please and possibly `prepareLimits` as well and maybe `geUserLimits`

Comment: Is unique constrain on `userId` and `channel` OR on `userId, channel` ??

Comment: If you are sure it is not already in the DB it could be that this method is called twice with same parameters. You could add debug messages to find out.
Show us the unique constraint as well.

Comment: Edited to answer your questions :)

Comment: `createOrUpdateLimits` is `void` while in code you got l

`limits = userDAO.createOrUpdateLimits(limitsToSave);`

Comment: Maybe you got duplication in `LimitsModel.CHANNELS` collection.

Comment: `createOrUpdateLimits` returns limits that have just been created with `prepareLimits`. That shouldn't really matter. There's also no duplication in `LimitsModel.CHANNELS`.

Comment: But this makes me think that code you provided is not the one that is actually used, thus we might miss something.

Comment: Ok the last thing you can do is just print collection of limitations that you are going to save. So print `limitsToSave` to see if there are no generated duplicates. If not - then the magic is happening somewhere else but you are just not aware of it..